# Searching php + mysql close words?

Tags: php, mysql, search, tags

First of all sorry for my english...

I have a tags field on database and  i am searching like

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE tags LIKE '%$keyword%' and tags LIKE '%$keyword%'
```

i seperate tags by  space   like ;

```
 america  england  france
```

i want to show you my table structure

```
id | title | tags

1    title1  america france
2    title2  american english
3    title3  england  french
```

for example when i want to search for "america"

results are title1  and title2  because  **america** and **american** tag look like same 
word..

how can i make them unique?  when i search for america , result should be only title1...

Thanks for your help , hope you understand my question.. Have a nice day

Edit :

Thanks to **Akam** he wrote solution

Comment: you can simply use `tags like 'keyword %'` add one space?

Comment: that's a bad table structure. you should normalize the design. each tag in its OWN record.

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM tbl
WHERE CONCAT(' ', tags, ' ') LIKE CONCAT('% ', 'america', ' %')
```

Please see fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/12ccf/1).

Comment: which then fails if the relevant tag is at the start or end of the field, without a leading/trailing space.

Comment: @MarcB i added a leading/trailing space, on both sides of the LIKE, i don't think it will fail

Answer (score 0):

You could also use MySQL's REGEXP instead of LIKE using the word boundary modifiers to only match entire words. Your query would look something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE tags REGEXP '[[:<:]]$keyword[[:>:]]';
```

This has the added bonus of letting you look for rows that match any (or all) of a given set of tags in a single query if you ever need to:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE tags REGEXP '[[:<:]]$keyword_one[[:>:]]|[[:<:]]$keyword_two[[:>:]]'
```

Note the pipe `|` character between both expressions in the REGEXP conditions, implying it will match any record that matches at least one of those tags.

I haven't personally tested performance on this approach, but have read in other StackOverflow posts that it is pretty much equivalent to a `LIKE` with a `%` wildcard in the beginning (since that type of query will cause MySQL not to use indexes). So I guess this is the best bet for you.

More info here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html